QuickFixJ : Failed to parse FIX message: quickfix.FieldException: The group 73 must set the delimiter field 11
<group name="73Tag" required="N">
  <field name="11Tag" required="N"/>
  <field name="37Tag" required="N"/>
  <field name="44Tag" required="N"/>
  <field name="66Tag" required="N"/>
  <field name="77Tag" required="N"/>
  <component name="122Tag" required="N"/>
  <field name="67Tag" required="N"/>
  <field name="87Tag" required="N"/>
  <field name="97Tag" required="N"/>
</group>

The counterparty is sending tag 73 with 37 tag but not 11 tag or any others in that group. The error is thrown when I try to parse using quickfixj. Could anyone tell me how can I avoid this and what changes can I make so, it does not happen anywhere using this datadictionary ? I thought required N means it does not expect that tag always.
Error says :
QuickFixJ : Failed to parse FIX message: quickfix.FieldException: The group 73 must set the delimiter field 11
I tried defining these flags but did not help:
DataDictionary dataDictionary = new DataDictionary(FIX44XML);
dataDictionary.setAllowUnknownMessageFields(true);
dataDictionary.setCheckFieldsOutOfOrder(false);
dataDictionary.setCheckUnorderedGroupFields(false);


The first tag in a group is always required.  It's not so important for the first member of the group, but vital for knowing when the second member starts.
It sounds like your counterparty has made changes to the default DD (which is normal, they all do this).  If they're going to start group 73 with tag 37, then you need to fix your DD so that group 73 starts with tag 37!
I assume your counterparty has documentation.  You need to get a hold of that and examine all of their message/field definitions, and update your DD accordingly.  Else you may have lots of avoidable decoding problems.

Thanks. They don't seem to have documentation. will try to get
